# Problem with the value portion of a drop down menu in ColdFusion

Tags: sql, forms, coldfusion

Here is what I have inside of my select statement:

```
<cfloop query name="country">
    <option value="#CountryName#"><cfoutput>#CountryName#</cfoutput></option>
</cfloop>
```

Everything works fine, but the value it passes to my URL filter is **#CountryName#**, not the actual country name (i.e. Canada).

How can I assign it the value of the country name and not the variable name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #CountryName# variable is not being evaluated because it is outside your output tags. Move the tags so they encompass your `value` too.

```
<cfoutput><option value="#CountryName#">#CountryName#</option></cfoutput>
```

Or just use a `<cfoutput query="...">` instead of `<cfloop>`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But, I have another question that I hope you could answer. How do I keep the selection that was made on the drop down menu after passing it through the URL? Right now it returns to the first option.

Comment: For cfselect's, use the "selected" attribute. For plain selects, compare the url value to the current #CountryName# inside the loop. If it matches, make it selected. ie `<cfif someCondition..> selected</cfif>` Google should turn up tons of examples on this.

Comment: @wahle509: You really should ask a new question rather than piggybacking on this one.

Comment: Oh, and if this answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it by clicking the big hollow checkmark.